# Telethon get media size before download

Tags: telegram, telethon

I have the following code to download media from chat:

```
getmessage = client.get_messages(dialog, limit=1000)
for message in getmessage:
    try:
        if message.media == None:
            print("message")
            continue
        else:
            print("Media**********")
            client.download_media(message)
```

I want to limit the download media size to X MB,
How can I get the media size in bytes before I download it?

Comment: If you do not need `getmessage` to be a list, I recommend you use `iter_messages` instead, since it will lazily fetch messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the [Objects Reference for `Message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/objects-reference.html#message) to find out the [`message.file`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.file) property. It will be a [`File`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.file.File) object with a [`size` property](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.file.File.size). Thus:

```py
if message.media:
    print(message.file.size, 'in bytes')
```

Note that `file` will be `None` for media like polls.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file size with this telegram bot api:  https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file

You should send file_id as parametr, you can find file_id inside your message object.